# Stacking frames to a 3D array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project in which I need to take about 30 images per second (no movie) and stack each 2D image to a 3D array using numpy array, without saving each 2D capture as a file (because is slow).

I found this Python code to take images as fast as possible, but i don't know how to stack all images fast to a 3D stack of images.

```
import io
import time
import picamera
#from PIL import Image

def outputs():
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    for i in range(40):
        # This returns the stream for the camera to capture to
        yield stream
        # Once the capture is complete, the loop continues here
        # (read up on generator functions in Python to understand
        # the yield statement). Here you could do some processing
        # on the image...
        #stream.seek(0)
        #img = Image.open(stream)
        # Finally, reset the stream for the next capture
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 80
    time.sleep(2)
    start = time.time()
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs(), 'jpeg', use_video_port=True)
    finish = time.time()
    print('Captured 40 images at %.2ffps' % (40 / (finish - start)))
```

**Does anyone of you know how to stack the 2D images taken in this code to a 3D numpy array using Python and the Raspberry Pi camera module? Without saving each 2D capture as a file**

Best regards, Agustín

Answer (score 1):

Any combination of [`numpy.dstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)/[`numpy.hstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)/[`numpy.vstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [`numpy.reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) works well, depending what you want to achieve exactly, for example:

```
>>> A,B,C = (np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])+i*10 for i in range(3))
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> B
array([[11, 12],
       [13, 14]])
>>> C
array([[21, 22],
       [23, 24]])

>>> D=np.reshape(np.vstack((A,B,C)), (3,2,2))
>>> D
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[11, 12],
        [13, 14]],

       [[21, 22],
        [23, 24]]])

>>> D[0]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> D[1]
array([[11, 12],
       [13, 14]])
>>> D[2]
array([[21, 22],
       [23, 24]])
>>>
```

Comment: Hi mescalinum. I think dstack can be a good choice, but i dont know how to implement in this case :(

Comment: `np.reshape(np.dstack((A,B,C)), (3,2,2))`